# Add static text in html generated by nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app, and I want to create static html files for all my routes.

I generate my static files successfully.

So after run `nuxt generate` I have e.g. these folders with `index.html` inside:

- buy/apple
- buy/orange
- buy/banana

My problem is here.

In my page I want to have this:

```
<h1>Buy {{fruit_name}}</h1>
```

and I want `fruit_name` be static on generated html file.

so e.g. for apple in final html I want to have:

```
<h1>Buy apple</h1>
```

for now *apple* is empty.

So what should I do to set this variable base on route name on generate time.

assume my routes are constant and I set my routes on `nuxt.config.js`

**UPDATE**

I try to change them in generated html files, but when I serve it changes not applied. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution:**

When generating routes pass payload to related page:

```
{
  route: `/fruit/${name}`,
  payload: { fruitName: name }
},
```

and set data in `asyncData` hook:

```
async asyncData({ params, error, payload }) {
  if (payload) {
    return {
      name: payload.name
    }
  }
}
```

and here a data set in component and can access it through component and it is static and set in generated html file for each route.